# Python approach to counting elements in a list of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, count, tuples, element

Given a list of a list of tuples like

```py
test = [[(2, 0.66835654), (0, 0.22021745), (1, 0.060669053), (6, 0.047858406)],
        [(10, 0.6511003), (0, 0.3458588)],
        [(4, 0.9961432)],
        [(10, 0.9917404)]]
```

What is the Pythonic way to create a list of counts of the first element of each tuple, using the first element of the tuple as the output list's index? So the tuple `(0, 0.2202)` would increment the counter for element `0` of the output list. For this example, the result would be `[2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]`.

Comment: It's not super clear what the counts are? Why does the result have more numbers than total tuples in `test`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your expected output rightly. Can you please explain more on that?

Comment: Sorry for my poorly worded question. The counts will be in a list where counts[0] will be incremented for each tuple whose first element is 0, counts[1] will be incremented for each tuple whose first element is 1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, there's an error in your listed expected output. See if this gives you what you're looking for. Note that it assumes the max of the first element of each tuple is 10 as in the example.

```py
test = [[(2, 0.66835654), (0, 0.22021745), (1, 0.060669053), (6, 0.047858406)],
        [(10, 0.6511003), (0, 0.3458588)],
        [(4, 0.9961432)],
        [(10, 0.9917404)]]

results = [0 for _ in range(11)]

for row in test:
    for element in row:
        results[element[0]] = results[element[0]] + 1
```

```py
> print(results)
> [2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

Comment: You're correct, I had an error and updated the question. This looks like an effective approach though I was thinking that an approach with list comprehension would be the best way.

Comment: A list comprehension will create a list from generated values. If you want `0` in the gaps, it won't necessarily be a one-step process like you're expecting.

Comment: @ScottS. why would a list-comprehension be 'the best way'? this for-loop is perfectly fine and pythonic. Pythonic does not mean 'use a list comprehension wherever you can'.

Answer (score 0):

```python
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(item[0] for sublist in test for item in sublist)
results = [counter[i] for i in range(11)]
```

This contains a double generator expression to deal with the nested lists, so it's arguable how Pythonic it is, but I like how succinct it is. You can use `itertools.chain` or `itertools.chain.from_iterable` if you prefer to keep the number of nested for-loops down.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what is the max value to put on the `range` call :

```py
from operator import itemgetter
max_value = max(map(itemgetter(0), sum(test, [])))
```